# Controller addresses of vitalik.eth

Tags: ens, eth-domain

When selecting the controller/resolver address of vitalik.eth, what does the list of .eth addresses on this page mean?

https://app.ens.domains/address/0x4976fb03C32e5B8cfe2b6cCB31c09Ba78EBaBa41/controller

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are other domains owned or controlled by the account at the top.

Comment: what does control mean? the top address somehow has access to the listed addresses and vitalik.eth??

Comment: why would another address be given control of another address?